# Random solution to a set of integer constraints

Tags: algorithm, random, linear-programming, constraint-programming

I have a set of integer constraints that I would like to solve. The constraints can consist of additions of variables that are greater than, less than or equal to some constant.

Example:

```
A >= 20
A <= 30
B <= 10
A + B <= 25
...
```

There will be hundreds of such simple constraints, and the constants are much larger values (hundreds of thousands) in practice.

However, I don't just want *a* solution to these constraints: I want a **random** solution from the solution space. That doesn't mean each solution has to have equal probability (I don't think that's possible without enumerating them all?) but what I want is that for instance for the variable A the solution will typically not be 20 or 30, but rather that values in between are just as likely (or even more likely) to be picked.

What techniques would be appropriate for this kind of problem? I'm having trouble knowing where to look, because most algorithms focus on finding optimal or fast or minimal solutions rather than random ones.

Comment: One (possibly extremely inefficient) method is [trial and error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_and_error): generate a random point in the space and test if it satisfies all the constraints. Repeat until a point passes.

Comment: Are the constraints also linear?  Are any of the terms the products of two or more variables?

Comment: What is the problem domian? It may shed some insight into how to approach the problem.

Comment: @TedHopp: that would be prohibitively expensive. Some kind of guided random search might be an option.

Comment: @phs no products, only additions as shown in the problem

Comment: @corsiKlauseHoHoHo I'm trying to procedurally generate a narrative graph.
Contrived Example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17511787/Story%20Graph%20Example.png

Comment: Do you have more information about the constraining inequalities?  Will the coefficients of your variables always be 1?

Comment: Trial and error is "prohibitively expensive" only if the volume of the feasible region is very small compared to the volume in which random trials are being generated. That depends entirely on the nature of the constraints and how you bound the trial generation space. That brings up another issue with trial and error: is the feasible region bounded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many Constraint Programming systems has a search heuristic (called "indomain_random" or something similar), which give solutions in random order (given some seed). Here's a MiniZinc model for a simple problem:

```
 var 20..30: A;
 var 0..10: B;     
 solve :: int_search([A,B], first_fail, indomain_random, complete) satisfy;
 constraint A + B <= 25;
 output [ show([A,B])];
```

Here's some solutions for a couple of seeds using Gecode's FlatZinc solver:

```
Seed   Solution
---------------
0      [22,0]
2      [25,0]
3      [22,2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My project is in Java and I've dabbled with JaCoP before and it seems like it supports this heuristic. I will check it out.

Comment: It seems to work like a charm. Was really easy to implement with JaCoP and I get seemingly random results. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It might be interesting to know that while using randomization in the heuristic will give random results, it does not guarantee any kind of distribution over the possible solutions.
There are more advanced techniques that can be used for efficiently heuristically sampling the full solution space, but that may be more than what is needed here. Two examples are http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips19/NIPS2006_0084.pdf and http://www.auai.org/uai2012/papers/160.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by establishing relationships between all nodes that interact with variables of other nodes.

Make a pass over your graph marking all nodes that depend on no other nodes as visited. Then iterate over each of the nodes that depend on those nodes, shrinking their range (increasing min and decreasing max) in such a way that their formulas are consistant. So if you have `A.min=10, A.max=20, B.min = 10, A+B=25` you can change `A.max` down to 15 (because B must be 10, and 25-10=15). You've just reduced the scope of A by 50%.

This gets easier if you establish a master node: if A+B=25, does A depend on B or does B depend on A? Making your graph a directed graph is much easier to deal with, as the algorithms are simpler in directed graphs.

Once you've done all this you will notice islands appear: this a is a good thing, because islands represent individual graphs that provide walls of separation - if you attempt a trial and error method, you only need to retry islands that failed to enter a consistent state.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a complete answer, but maybe useful, and too long for a comment:

It may help you to know that the solution space is convex.  Meaning, if you have two solutions `A1, B1, C1` and `A2, C2, B2`, then any triple in between them is also a solution.

(Here, "in between" means that there is some real number `t` in the range `[0,1]`, so that:

- `Anew = t * A1 + (1 - t) * A2`
- `Bnew = t * B1 + (1 - t) * B2`
- `Cnew = t * C1 + (1 - t) * C2`

To see why, you can just try plugging these expressions for `Anew, Bnew, Cnew` into your inequalities, and the inequalities will expand as true because they do so for `A1, B1, C1` and `A2, B2, C2`.)

You can use this information to limit the region of `n` space you need to search.  For instance, if you find one solution, and you want to know how far out in some direction your solution space extends, you can run something like a binary search down towards the known solution.  Etc...